# Full Width Table of Contents in Two Column Document (any document class)

Tags: table-of-contents, two-column

How can one create a full width table of contents in a two column document, independent of `documentclass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package for this. Switch between any number of columns using the `multicols` environment.

This solution should work for any document class as asked by you.

**The Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{My Contents}
\lipsum

\section{More Contents}

\lipsum

\section{And More Contents}

\lipsum
\section{And More My Contents}

\lipsum
\section{And More}

\lipsum


\end{multicols}


\end{document
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: What about RevTex4, which is incompatible with multicols?